# Can I use similar `dirname(__FILE__) . ` to import a PHP file like this?

Tags: php

In my project directories:

[image]

I am in `test01.php`, if `test01.php` at the same level with `cache`, I can use below code to import the `A.php` with absolute path:

```
include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache/A.php';
```

But how about in this scene?

Comment: Use `..` to go back a step. `'/../cache/A.php`

Comment: Oh, thanks bro. little am I think of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be calling the same file from the same place each time, you can use one of the magic constants to do something like this:

`include_once __DIR__ . '/../cache/A.php';`

[Click here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for more info on magic constants.